# INSERT INTO with SELECT and some DEFAULT values

Tags: mysql, sql

I've got the tables

```
person
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name         | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and

```
chatroom
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| col1      | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| col2      | int(11) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

and I want to execute the following statement (for each `person` add a row in `chatroom` with the respective `person.id` and `DEFAULT` and `NULL` values for the `id` and `col2` columns)

```
INSERT INTO chatroom (DEFAULT, col1, NULL) SELECT DEFAULT, id AS col1, NULL FROM person;
```

but it does not work.
Can someone correct the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `id` field is `auto_increment`, so you can just leave it out of the query and it will automatically set the row to the next value.  Also, since `col2` has a default value of `NULL`, it too can be left out of the query.  It will be set to its default automatically.

```
INSERT INTO chatroom (col1) SELECT id FROM person
```

Answer (score 1):

Because your `chatroom` table has `id` column as auto-incremant so there is no need to pass value for this column. This column have automatic value when new row inserted in table. So no need of `DEFAULT`.

Second, `col2` will accept the `null` as per your table definition, so there is also no need to pass value for this column also until you have some value which you need to put in this column.

So you have to only specify column for this, you have value

So, if you want to insert `null` value in `col2` column then use this

```
INSERT INTO chatroom (col1) 
SELECT id FROM person;
```

So, if you want to insert some value in `col2` column then use this

```
INSERT INTO chatroom (col1,col2) 
SELECT id, col2 FROM person;
```

Answer (score 0):

The first list has to contain the column names, not values. To insert the default value, just omit it from the list:

```
INSERT INTO chatroom (col1, col2)
SELECT id, NULL
FROM person
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to include `DEFAULT` in the query. Try this:

`INSERT INTO chatroom (col1, col2) SELECT id AS col1, NULL FROM person;`

When you don't include a column in the INSERT statement, it attempts to use the default value (if available).